# Restriction of a Schwartz distribution to a hyperplane.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Suppose $u\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m)$.

In general, it is well known that we cannot define a restriction map $\mathcal{R}:\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m)\rightarrow \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which generalises the restriction map for continuous functions $u(\cdot,\cdot)\mapsto u(\cdot,0)$.

To me, it seems that the natural generalisation to make is

$$(\mathcal{R}u)(\phi):=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}u(\phi\otimes\eta_\epsilon) $$

for $u$ such that the above limit exists for each $\phi\in \mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $\eta_\epsilon$ is a fixed approximate identity.

Is this the sensible construction to make? And is there a convenient classification of the distributions $u$ that satisfy this property?

(This question has arisen in me trying to understand how one can in general define the analogue of the heat kernel for linear differential operators in $(x,t)$ of the form $P=(\partial_t-L_x)$ and prove the equivalence of such a solution with the notion of a fundamental solution $Pu=\delta(x)\delta(t)$. A solution kernel for such an operator should be a distribution $p\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R})$ that in a sense  restricts to a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n\times \{y\}\times \{t\}$ which converges to $\delta_y$ in the sense of distributions as $t\rightarrow 0$.)

Comment: The result of that limit depends in the approximate identity being used. You can see this already with easy distributions like the ones given by directional derivatives at a point in your hyperplane with respect to a direction transversal to that hyperplane.

Comment: Ah, right! Thanks for pointing this out, I missed this difficulty.

Presumably it is best then to restrict discussion of solution kernels (of the sort mentioned in the bottom of my posted question) to the case where such kernels are given by functions?

(Unless one wants to use the wavefront set of u to determine when such a restriction can be defined. I think a result of this kind is proven in Hormander I, which does not apply to operators such as transversal differential operators to the hyperplane.)